# How to recognize Facebook User-Agent in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am trying to recognize **Facebook** User-Agent in **Node.js**.

i have tried https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent  but when i hit my URL in Facebook it return nothing .

I want to detect **Google**,**Facebook**,**Twitter** so , i can redirect on some another **URL**.

Please help me how will i detect this.